How to reset cum_sum value based on condition in polars
I have the following DF on which i am trying to construct a new column which is will be cum_sum.
import polars as pl
pl.Config(tbl_rows=20)
df= pl.LazyFrame({
    "a" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "b" : [33,35,33,32,33,37,33,29,34,36],
    "c" : [33,35,35,35,35,37,37,37,37,37],
})
df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('b') == pl.col('c')).then(0).otherwise(1).alias('temp'))
df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('temp') == 0).then(0).otherwise(pl.col('temp').cum_sum()).alias('c_sum_n'))

Currently i am getting the following output ,
>>> df.collect()
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ temp ┆ c_sum_n │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i32  ┆ i32     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 0    ┆ 0       │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 0    ┆ 0       │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1    ┆ 1       │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 1    ┆ 2       │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1    ┆ 3       │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 0    ┆ 0       │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 4       │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 5       │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 6       │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 7       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────────┘

but the desired output i am looking is
>>> df.collect()
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ temp ┆ c_sum_n │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i32  ┆ i32     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 0    ┆ 0       │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 0    ┆ 0       │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1    ┆ 1       │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 1    ┆ 2       │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1    ┆ 3       │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 0    ┆ 0       │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 1       │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 2       │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 3       │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 1    ┆ 4       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────────┘

i,e when col b == col c, i would like to have cum_sum value reset to zero and start all over again. Any help, either in python polars or rust polars will be helpful.

just saying, could you just use column c as grouping - .with_columns(pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("c"))

Here's one way to do this using over:
We extract the predicate col("b") == col("c"), then we do a cum_sum of ~predicate over the cum_sum of predicate.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "b": [33, 35, 33, 32, 33, 37, 33, 29, 34, 36],
        "c": [33, 35, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37],
    }
)

predicate = pl.col("b") == pl.col("c")

df = df.with_columns((~predicate).cum_sum().over(predicate.cum_sum()).alias("c_sum_n"))

print(df)

Output:
shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ c_sum_n │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 0       │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 0       │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1       │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 2       │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 3       │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 0       │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 1       │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 2       │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 3       │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 4       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┘

How this works:
Doing a cum_sum on the predicate gives us different values for each group which is exactly what we need to split the cum_sum over ~predicate:
print(df.with_columns(group=predicate.cum_sum()))

Output:
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ group │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32   │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 1     │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 2     │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 2     │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 2     │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 2     │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 3     │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 3     │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 3     │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 3     │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 3     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘


.rle_id() can be used to generate a "group id" for the "streaks".
>>> df.with_columns(rle_id = (pl.col.b != pl.col.c).rle_id())
shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ rle_id │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 0      │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 0      │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1      │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 1      │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1      │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 2      │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 3      │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 3      │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 3      │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 3      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘

Which you can .cum_sum().over()
df.with_columns(
   (pl.col.b != pl.col.c).cum_sum()
      .over((pl.col.b != pl.col.c).rle_id())
      .alias("cum_sum")
)

shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ cum_sum │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 0       │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 0       │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1       │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 2       │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 3       │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 0       │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 1       │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 2       │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 3       │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 4       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┘


Although i had to accept the other answer this is indeed a great answer. Thanks for the same :) by the way Is there a rle_id equivalent in rust? (My actual implementation is in rust, but as per my observation we usually tend to get answers faster in python, i went ahead and asked in python)

@Akash It's there. You need to enable the rle feature. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/f6b19ad464881bca7353798162360166982e0f99/crates/polars-plan/src/dsl/mod.rs#L1658

Looking at your data, you could also use column c for grouping:
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("c")
        .alias("c_sum_n")
    )

But if this is not relevant, another way of doing that could be:
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_range(pl.len()).over(
            pl.when(pl.col.b == pl.col.c).then(pl.col.b).forward_fill())
        )
        .alias("c_sum_n")
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ c_sum_n │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 0       │
│ 1   ┆ 35  ┆ 35  ┆ 0       │
│ 2   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 1       │
│ 3   ┆ 32  ┆ 35  ┆ 2       │
│ 4   ┆ 33  ┆ 35  ┆ 3       │
│ 5   ┆ 37  ┆ 37  ┆ 0       │
│ 6   ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 1       │
│ 7   ┆ 29  ┆ 37  ┆ 2       │
│ 8   ┆ 34  ┆ 37  ┆ 3       │
│ 9   ┆ 36  ┆ 37  ┆ 4       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┘


First of all thanks for taking time to answer. I understand for the asked data the answer is correct, but my actual data is different, it is not even int. So it might not work directly anyway thanks for spending time on this. Appreciate.
